# T-SQL : How can I retrieve the OUTPUT from an INSERT statement with PEAR DB?

Tags: php, sql-server, pear

This is my first time using T-SQL

I am currently trying to get the last inserted ID from an INSERT statement in T-SQL using this query:

```
INSERT INTO TICKET( STATE, RECORD_DATE, ID_USER, TICKET_TYPE, TICKET_COM)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID_TICKET AS lastId
VALUES ( 1, CONVERT(datetime, '24/02/2022 09:25:53'), 100, 1, 'It does not work')
```

As you've guessed, ID_TICKET is the identity, with auto_increment.
When I run this through MS SQL server management studio, I get the intended result : one row, with a unique lastId column containing the value of the last inserted id.

However on PHP, when I am running this using the `query()` method from PEAR database, I am running into some issue.
From reading the documentation, `DB->query()` will only return a resource in case of a SELECT query, while an INSERT query will just return a DB_OK type of answer: which is exactly what I am getting in PHP.
Hence my question : how can I retrieve the OUTPUT from an INSERT statement with PEAR DB?

I'd like to continue using PEAR, as I am adding functionality to an existing intranet heavily relying on it.
It is hosted on IIS 7 with SQL Server 9.0 using PHP 5.2.9 and PEAR DB 1.1.2.2.

Comment: I suspect you may need to run `select last_insert_id()` in a second query.

Comment: OUTPUT gives a table result set, not a variable. An alternative is to capture the output into a table variable with a sorting column. Then select TOP(1) from a descending order.

Comment: It does indeed give a result set in MSSMS, as expected.  The problem was more about PEAR DB that would automatically send back a DB_OK (an int(1)) if the query was an INSERT.  It would only send back a result set ion the case of a SELECT.
https://pear.php.net/package/DB/docs/latest/DB/DB_common.html#methodquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just did a simple INSERT by removing the `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID_TICKET AS lastId` line.
I then did a second query() call immediately after : `SELECT @@IDENTITY as lastId` and it now gives the desired results.

Pretty much what Álvaro González suggested.

Now, following Dan Guzman sugestion and adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beggining of my original `INSERT` with the `OUTPUT` clause indeed solved the problem !
I now get a result set with a unique row and column lastId as desired.
My hat off to both of you.

Comment: Yes, I should have said `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. The function I mentioned is probably from another DBMS.

Comment: I know nothing about PearDB but it the `OUTPUT` clause method might work if you add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the insert batch. Rowcount messages can interfere with result sets with some client APIs unless the code handles multiple results.